# One Rewrite Rule Works... Another Almost Identical Rule Does Not

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Maybe someone can fill me in on why the following from my .htaccess file is behaving strangely:

```
RewriteRule    ^brand/b([0-9]+)/?$    articles.php?id=b$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^brand/h([0-9]+)/?$    categories.php?id=h$2    [NC,L]
```

With these rules, this

```
example.com/brand/b1234
```

redirects to

```
example.com/articles.php?id=b1234
```

But this

```
example.com/brand/h1234
```

does not redirect to

```
example.com/categories.php?id=h1234
```

as it should.

Am I missing anything from the code in my .htacess that would cause one to work but not the other?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `$1` I suspect in your second destination instead of `$2` as the number refers to the capture group in the regex of which you have only 1.

Comment: This was my first thought since I wasn't sure which it should be, but neither works, $1 or $2.

Comment: "redirects to" - do you really mean "redirect"? Or "rewrite"? If you are seeing a _redirect_ then this may be an earlier (erroneous) _cached_ redirect and neither of these rules are actually working?!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
# incoming request neither file nor a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^brand/b([0-9]+)/?$ articles.php?id=b$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^brand/h([0-9]+)/?$ categories.php?id=h$1 [NC,L]
```

You have to indeed put $1 instead of $2.

Comment: I copy and pasted this exactly and it still doesn't work. What on Earth?

Comment: Do you have some other rule and what error are you getting?

Comment: No, there's nothing else in the entire .htaccess file at the minute. It just doesn't work, the first rule works perfectly, but I'm getting nothing but dead links where the second rule should be rewriting and it isn't.

Comment: Do one thing, instead of category try to rewrite to article all the rules for debugging.

Comment: _Aside:_ Those `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule`.